# Create PFBC forms from mysql

Tags: php, forms

I found a good looking class for form creating. Hovewer I need to create forms dinamically, using output from database. Forms are being created this way:

```
$form->addElement(new Element\Textbox("Name:", "Name", array(
    "required" => 1
)));
```

So, If I want to add a different form I have to change `new Element\Textbox` to `new Element\Password`. Is it possible to create forms based on database results something like this:

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
$form->addElement(new Element\$field->type("Name:", "Name", array(
    "required" => 1
)));
}
```

Right now it looks not right for me, and of course it's not working. So my question is, can I output this forms dinamically in different way, or should I check for another class ?

Comment: check the output of $field and be sure about the letter case and you can use "ucfirst" if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if $field->type is valid string of class name, for example "Password". Try to use:

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $className = "\\PFBC\\Element\\{$field->type}";
    $form->addElement(new $className("Name:", "Name", array(
         "required" => 1
    )));
}
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting this error: ` Class 'Element\Textbox' `, if I put `Element\Textbox` instead `$className` then it works ok..

Comment: `Fatal error: Class 'Element\Textbox' not found in index.php on line 3`

Comment: Excuse me, I changed line to fit current code, actually it's 93 where `$form->addElement(new $className("Name:", "Name", array` line is.

Comment: Sorry, I missed one. You need to have in $className a full path to class with namespace. So should be like $className = "\\PFBC\\Element\\{$field->type}"; I have updated an answer.